# ARC enabled but I can still use release and autorelease in my AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, appdelegate

I have ARC enabled in my iOS application, which I thought meant you weren't able to explicitly call `retain`, `release` or `autorelease` without setting the `-fno-objc-arc` flag. Apparently this isn't true for the application delegate. I checked my AppDelegate file under the "Compile Sources" section of the "Build Phases" for my project, and it doesn't list any compiler flags set for me AppDelegate file. However, I can explicitly call `release` and `autorelease`, but not `retain`. Is this evidence of witchcraft, or did the Apple engineers resort to hacks to get ARC to work?

Answer (score 2):

If you can send these messages, ARC is off.

You can check using

```
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error "ARC is off"
#endif
```

Comment: **I have ARC enabled in my iOS application,** I think he excluded this class from ARC.

Comment: @Nikolai: That's a pretty bold statement. How then can I send `release` and `autorelease` but not `retain`? @Anoop: I stated in my question that the app delegate has not been excluded. Are you sure you read it?

Comment: Copy/paste the raw compilation line from the build log into your question.   More likely than not, the compiler say the first error and decided that repeatedly reminding you of the same thing was a waste of time.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Something is broken in your project. Maybe funny preprocessor defines or whatever. ARC forbids to send any of `retain`, `release`, `autorelease`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: It's possible. I created a new project and it's not possible to use either `retain`, `release` or `autorelease`. I guess I'll just chalk it up to magic.

Comment: @bbum: My project compiles fine. There are no errors and none of the warnings are relevant.

Comment: @freeasinbeer How entirely odd.  If it is a sample project, zip it up and send it to me (bbum @ any random apple related domain).  I'll have a look and file a bug.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer .. or, rather, put it in your public dropbox and edit your question adding a link to it.

Comment: bbum: The sample project I made didn't allow me to use these messages, just like I would expect with ARC enabled. But the large project I'm working on is the issue. I'd send it, but I'm not sure the client would be happy about that ^_^  Thanks for the offer!